# Table row onclick event that runs codebehind

Tags: asp.net, dom-events, code-behind

I've inherited an ASP.NET project that has poorly designed HTML; in one section, the `<TR>` tags are wrapped with an  tag to allow for "click the row to view the information" functionality. The code is:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ViewArticle" runat="server" CommandName="Navigate" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>' >
    <tr runat="server" class="list_item">
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
        <td>some data</td>
    </tr>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
<tr runat="server" class="list_item" onclick="doRowPostbackFunction('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>');">
    <td>some data</td>
    <td>some data</td>
    <td>some data</td>
</tr>
```

How do I go about tying a JavaScript `onclick` event to the codebehind?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want your JavaScript to initiate a server code ("codebehind") - method/function;

After the server has rendered your page, you're in the client scope - and the only way to communicate with your server code is via a web service.

Another way of not using a web service is rendering/injecting the data from the server onto your page, thus you have the data available in the client.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can do the following and trigger a postback:

```
<table>
    <tr id="1">
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("table tr").click(function (e) {
            //alert the row index that was clicked
            alert($("table tr").index(this));

            //alert the id of the row
            alert($(this).attr("id"));

            //submit the form...
        });
    });
</script>
```

OR use the onclick event of the row...

`<tr onclick="doPostBack('<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>')">`

...and trigger a javascript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doPostBack(id)
    {
        //submit form
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your page (or control, if that's inside a control) implement [IPostBackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx) interface and use [ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx) method (using [Page.ClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clientscript.aspx) propery to get a reference to ClientScriptManager) to get a js-method-call-string which will make a postback to your page. As a control argument to GetPostBackEventReference method use your page.
Then set onclick property of tr to that js-method-call-string.

---

### Example

In aspx:

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="<%= _jsPostBackCall %>;">
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h1>
    <asp:Literal ID="litMessage" runat="server" />
</h1>
```

In codebehind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    protected String _jsPostBackCall;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // "myTr" will be passed as an argument to RaisePostBackEvent method
        _jsPostBackCall = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "myTr");
    }

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        switch (eventArgument)
        {
            case "myTr":
                HandleTrClick();
                break;

            // you can add other controls that need postback processing here

            default:
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }

    private void HandleTrClick()
    {
        litMessage.Text = "Tr clicked.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. That looks confusing. I'll dive right in and try to figure it out. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Loki Thanks. I'm trying it out step by step, but can't seem to get past

`<tr onclick="<%# _jsPostBackCall %>;">`

In the view source, I see the literal

`<%# _jsPostBackCall %>`

Comment: I got the same issue when using `<%=`, so I tried the `<%#`; all the rest of the code was using the `<%#`.  Either way, it outputs `<%= _jsPostBackCall %>` instead of the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
__doPostBack(eventName, eventArgs);
```

Here eventName is code-behind event handler