# onclick for table TD

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, onclick, html-table

Trying to do an `onClick` a JS function for a `<td>`.

```
<td id="Td10" runat="server" onclick="doPostBack('<%#Eval("ID")%>')">                                      </td>
```

is flagging as

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

but I cant see how it is not formatted properly?

any suggestions?

I obtained this example from:

[Table row onclick event that runs codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419115/table-row-onclick-event-that-runs-codebehind)

--INCLUDED ON EDIT---

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function doPostBack(id) {
           alert("MAP ID is " + id);
        }
</script>
```

Console is throwing error 'UNEXPECTED TOKEN <' with

```
<td id="MainContent_lvDataStores_Td10_0" onclick="doPostBack(&lt;%#Eval(&quot;ID&quot;)%>)">
```

it removes < and includes <??

Comment: Please check my answer, it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:-

```
<td id="Td10" runat="server" onclick="doPostBack('<%#Eval("ID")%>')">
```

with:-

```
<td id="Td10" runat="server" onclick='<%#"doPostBack("+Eval("ID")+")" %>'></td>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ahh yes thats for the help S